# What's the difference between difference between NF_NETLINK_CONNTRACK_EXP_DESTROY and NF_NETLINK_CONNTRACK_DESTROY?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a Netlink socket, subscribed to destroy events, by using `bind` with `NF_NETLINK_CONNTRACK_DESTROY` OR'd into the `groups` parameter.

When looking through the [nfnetlink_compat.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/nfnetlink_compat.h#L13), though, I see that there're more flags than just NEW, UPDATE, and DESTROY - there's an EXP_XYZ variant for each flag as well:

```
#define NF_NETLINK_CONNTRACK_NEW            0x00000001
#define NF_NETLINK_CONNTRACK_UPDATE         0x00000002
#define NF_NETLINK_CONNTRACK_DESTROY        0x00000004
#define NF_NETLINK_CONNTRACK_EXP_NEW        0x00000008
#define NF_NETLINK_CONNTRACK_EXP_UPDATE     0x00000010
#define NF_NETLINK_CONNTRACK_EXP_DESTROY    0x00000020
```

I can't find the EXP_XYZ flags documented anywhere I've looked. Where can I find more information on these flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These flags exist to [handle notifications about conntrack *expectations*](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter-devel/msg15031.html), which are conntrack `RELATED` states that are stored in a table and handled by the kernel; you can be notified if an expectation is being added, deleted or modified. This table can be manipulated by user programs like [conntrack-tools toolset](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html) but are [used by kernel modules like the FTP and SIP helpers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#Connection_tracking_helpers)

That said, I've never had to use this feature directly: it's usually handled automatically.